# Error: 'tools:replace='android:label' is not recognized' when building Flutter Android app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest

## Introducing flutter_gromore_ads 1.3.0，report the following error：

```
/Users/miaoyu/Desktop/Workspace/app.wallpaper.notes.flutter.cn/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(壁纸备忘录) from (unknown)
    is also present at [com.gromore.cn:gromore-sdk:3.9.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:37:5-90:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

## When I added the line of tools: replace="android: label" to the code, the following error was reported：

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Error while evaluating property 'namespace' of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'.
      > Failed to query the value of property 'namespace'.
         > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/miaoyu/Desktop/Workspace/app.wallpaper.notes.flutter.cn/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 44; columnNumber: 39; 已经为元素 "application" 指定绑定到名称空间 "http://schemas.android.com/tools" 的属性 "replace"。

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

## How to solve this error, please help me！